# Spring boot shut down after it starts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, console

When I try to start my Spring Boot application throw Eclipse evrething is okey.
But when I do into project folder and try to start application throw console (by command "java -jar target/MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar") I get some issue which I couldn't even undertand what they are talking about :)
Here is screenshot below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYxMU.jpg)

Any ideas what should I try?

Answer (score 0):

In your snapshot the `datasource` would be `closed`.

The `application seems to be running`.

What are your `datasource` settings?

Comment: https://github.com/6ruceWayne/BankTestTask

If I correctly understood you - all my settings are in application.properties and only about DB link, log-pass, hibernate.ddl-auto=update and changed server port

Comment: @BruceVVayne please can you post you complete log? I get your sources and can't find the `shutdown completed`message. Maybe you have a problen with the database connection?

Comment: Would I have some problem If I could start application from Eclipse?
What should I check?

Comment: If your application runs I think you have no problem. Can you access the MVC controller and get the user list or add a new one to the database?

Answer (score 0):

you have to take off the dependency to JPA if you don't use Hibernate or add something to application.properties .